# Saving high resolution images from google maps/earth

Tags: image, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

So, the situation:
I need to save high resolution images from google maps of an area given by latitude and longitude coords.
Of course I know that from google earth I can save high res. images, but want to save the image as it looks like in google maps, e.g. without satellite images, so only roads, area names, etc.
With print screen I'm not able to create high res. images in google maps, so,
is there any way to save high res. images? For example with maps API, or something.
Again, I need to save an area's high res. image given by latitude/longitude coords.

Thanks in advance for the answers.

Comment: That sounds like it is against the terms of service.

Answer (score 2):

For some higher res imagery, you might want to use the Static Maps api, using the `scale` paramater.

Some more info below.

http://googlegeodevelopers.blogspot.com/2011/08/go-large-with-high-resolution-support.html
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/staticmaps/?csw=1#scale_values

Comment: Thanks, it's really useful. However, the resolution it provides still not high enough, I wrote a little application which accepts SW and NE latlng coords, and downloads tiles on the highest zoom level, and then assembles the tiles into one image, thus creating a very high res. image :)

Comment: I'd love to try this application :)

Comment: Any chance you could share it?